# Shortest Paths Between Adjacent Points on a Network

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, distance, network, distance-matrix

With the project I'm currently working on I need to calculate how much the total length of the network increases as I expand it from one node to the next. I have the road network as a line layer (32673 features) and nodes on the road network as a point layer (3461 features). A segment of these layers as viewed on QGIS is as follows:

[image: A segment of my line and point layers]

As part of this project what I need to do is similar to `v.net.allpairs` in GRASS GIS but **instead of a distance matrix connecting every combination of pairs on the network what I need is to connect pairs of adjacent (nearest) points along the network and find the length of each connection**. I'm open to suggestions using any type of open source GIS software but prefer QGIS or GRASS GIS.